# Synchronize files with spaces with WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, ftp, winscp

```
open ftps:/xxx
synchronize local E:/test logs \test logs
```

Script is failing due to spaces in directory names.
Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [wrap the path with spaces to double quotes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scripting#quotes). Also, you seem to have the slashes wrong.

```
synchronize local "E:\test logs" "/test logs"
```

Comment: Thanks .. it worked